# Why am I getting the error "the modifier 'public' / 'private' not valid for this item(CS0106) all over my program?

Tags: c#, getter-setter

I'm getting this error in almost every case I've used 'private' or 'public'. I recently changed my classes to just  `get; set;` from...

```
public string Title
{
    get { return title; }
    set { title = value; }

}
```

to...

```
public static string Title
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

there errors are showing up in...

```
private void cBxEmployment_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //sets the job list combo box to visible if "Employed" or "Self Employed" is selected by user, if not selected jobs list combo box is not visible.
    if (cBxEmployment.SelectedIndex == 0 || cBxEmployment.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        lblJob.Visible = true;
        cBxJob.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        lblJob.Visible = false;
        cBxJob.Visible = false;
    }
}

private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //when exit button is clicked user will get a message box asking if they want to exit, if yes program closes
    DialogResult answer = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (answer == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        //close program
        Application.Exit();
    }
}

private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cBxTitle.SelectedIndex = -1;
    txtFName.Text = "";
    txtLastname.Text = "";
    txtDOB.ResetText();
    cBxEmployment.SelectedIndex = -1;
    cBxJob.SelectedIndex = -1;

    cBxRelationship.SelectedIndex = -1;

    cBxTitle.Focus();
```

and so on...

even if I change it from public to private or vice versa it still throws up this error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include the full source code of the file/class and append the full error message you get from the compiler.

Comment: Why did you add `static` to the property definitions?

Comment: I think you have a misplaced closing-brace (`}`) and so the C# compiler is interpreting your class-level members as namespace-level members or nested-members where those access-modifiers don't apply.

Answer (score 1):

You have a nested function, In C# these are called local functions and don't have scope. 
So you need to remove the access modifier.

From [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions):

> local functions cannot include the **static** modifier. Including the **static** keyword generates compiler error CS0106, "The modifier 'static' is not valid for this item

Answer (score 1):

You also changed your properties to `static` like in your example: `public static string Title`

It should be

```
public string Title
{
    get;
    set;
}
```